# Make PHP page after querying data on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, templates

Hi guys im a newbie on PHP (I'm more versed on C# and Visual Studio) so I got this problem where I want to make a page that will be linked on the name of a person after consulting on php and mysql. I got a template that needs to be filled up with names, career and ID from my database but I have no idea how to do it.

So i got my students page like:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

 $sql = 'SELECT lastname, 
    name, 
        id,
        career,

 FROM estudiantes
 ORDER BY apellido';

 $q = $conn->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
 die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SOCIAL WORK STUDENTS LIST:</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <h1>Estudiantes</h1>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Name         </th>
 <th>Lastname       </th>
 <th>ID         </th>
 <th>Career         </th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
 <tr>
 <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['lastname'])?></th>
 <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['name']); ?></th>
 <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['id']); ?></th>
  <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['career']); ?></th>
 </tr>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Where in name and lastname I have to put a link that will take me to a template with the name and career.

Something like

template.php:
Student: "name" "lastname" id number "id" , student of "career". Have approved Social Labor on "day_display".

Any help will be appreciated.

Greetings, sorry for my english (spanish speaker here lol)

Comment: So what's the question? Questions on SO should have a clear problem statement and should ask a clear question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this

```
 <tbody>
 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()){ 
 $url = 'template.php?firstname='.$r['name'].'&lastname='.$r['lastname'].'&id='.$r['id'].'&career='.$r['career'];
 ?>
 <tr>
 <th><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['lastname'])?></a></th>
 <th><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['name']); ?></a></th>
 <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['id']); ?></th>
  <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['career']); ?></th>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
```

I modify your table and add `<a>` tag with link on your template with all the data you need to transfer on template page
You can grab values on template page with $_GET['id'], $_GET['name']...

Now you can easily get all values and on template display this values in any way you need.
And also template.php can be something like this

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['lastname']) && !empty($_GET['lastname']) && isset($_GET['career']) && !empty($_GET['career'])){
    \\$day = date() Here set up any format you need
    echo "Student: $_GET[name] $_GET[lastname] id number $_GET[id] , student of $_GET[career]. Have approved Social Labor on $day";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed... You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, here's what i think you are asking about.

In your current code, while iterating students, put together a link to the student's detail, and pass the student's id on the query string:

```
<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
<tr>
<th><a href="template.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['lastname'])?></a></th>
<th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['name']); ?></th>
<th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['id']); ?></th>
<th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['career']); ?></th>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And then you should create a `template.php` file and query the student by it's id:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM estudiantes WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id'];
    $q = $conn->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //  Get the one and only result
    $student = $q[0];

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>VIEW STUDENT DETAILS</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1><?php echo $student['name'] ?> <?php echo $student['lastname'] ?></h1>
<p>First Name: <?php echo $student['name'] ?></p>
<p>Last Name: <?php echo $student['lastname'] ?></p>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very well explained!

Comment: Hey, I tested this method and I got back a Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on boolean... And i really don't know whats causing it...

Comment: what version of php are you using?